# What options are available for a vb.net developer when using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: vb.net, fluent-nhibernate

I've been using c# for the past year and I enjoy the power you get with Fluent NHibernate.  One question that I get from friends is "nice but how can vb.net programmers use this?"

So for example- the below is a c# mapping class.  How would someone do this with vb.net?

```
public class PostMap : ClassMap<post>
{
public PostMap()
{
Table("Posts");
Id(x => x.ID);
Map(x => x.PublishDate, "PublishDate");
Map(x => x.Title, "Title");
Map(x => x.uri, "uri");
Map(x => x.Content, "Content");

HasMany(x => x.CommentCollection).KeyColumn("PostID");
HasManyToMany(x => x.TagCollection).Table("TagMap").ParentKeyColumn("PostID").ChildKeyColumn("TagID");
}
}
```

My fault - the above does translate

What about trying to create the fluent interface for config though?

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Blog")))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
.ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"));

return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If your friends are **that lazy** you might suggest them using [an online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/):

```
Public Class PostMap Inherits ClassMap(Of post)
    Public Sub New()
        Table("Posts")
        Id(Function(x) x.ID)
        Map(Function(x) x.PublishDate, "PublishDate")
        Map(Function(x) x.Title, "Title")
        Map(Function(x) x.uri, "uri")
        Map(Function(x) x.Content, "Content")

        HasMany(Function(x) x.CommentCollection).KeyColumn("PostID")
        HasManyToMany(Function(x) x.TagCollection).Table("TagMap").ParentKeyColumn("PostID").ChildKeyColumn("TagID")
    End Sub
End Class

Private Shared Function CreateSessionFactory() As ISessionFactory
    Dim cfg = Fluently.Configure() _
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(Function(c) c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Blog"))) _
        .Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())) _
        .ExposeConfiguration(Function(x) x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))

    Return cfg.BuildSessionFactory()
End Function
```